# Equicontinuity of a family of functions $(g_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to solve preliminary problem 4.26 in Pugh's Analysis 2e. The problem is laid out as follows:

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous maps $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int_0^1(f_n(y))^2dy \leq 5$$ for all $n$. Define $g_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$g_n(x) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{x+y} f_n(y) dy$$

The problem ask two things: to find a constant that bounds $g_n(x)$ from above (which I've done already using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) and to prove that $g_n(x)$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence. I would like to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem to prove this and by solving the first part of this problem, I believe I'm halfway there (by proving $g_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded). The only part I'm having trouble with is how to prove that $g_n(x)$ is equicontinuous. I think I should start by subtracting $g_n(x)$ from $$g(x) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{x+y}f(y)dy$$ and then prove that this is less than some $\epsilon > 0$ for $|x-y| < \delta$, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to prove $g_n$ is uniformly convergent, and not that it is equicontinuous. 

By the way there is no reason why the limit should have the same form.

Comment: Thank you, you're right about the convergent part. I appreciate you setting me on the right path! As for the limit part, the only aspect of $g_n(x)$ that is dependent on $n$ is the $f_n(y)$ component. So wouldn't it have the same form, except for that term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,x'\in [0,1]$. For any $n$
$$g_n(x)-g_n(x')=\int_0^1\Big(\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x'+y}\Big)f_n(y).$$
So $$|g_n(x)-g_n(x')|\le \sqrt{|x-x'|} \int_0^1 f_n(y).$$

Moreover $\int_0^1 f_n(y)$ is bounded uniformly in $n$ by the first hypothesis (and Hölder inequality).

Thus we get that all the $g_n$s are $1/2$-Hölder continuous with the same constant, hence equicontinuous.

If you are unfamiliar with Hölder continuity let us observe that in general, if there exists any positive function $h\colon  [0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty)$ such that
$$|g_n(x)-g_n(x')|\le h(|x-x'|)$$
for every $n$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$, then the sequence $(g_n)_{n}$ is equicontinuous.